# sbatch sends compute node to 'drained' status

Tags: slurm, sbatch

On newly installed and configured compute nodes in our small cluster I am unable to submit slurm jobs using a batch script and the 'sbatch' command. After submitting, the requested node changes to the 'drained' status. However, I can run the same command interactively using 'srun'.

Works: 
    `srun -p debug --ntasks=1 --nodes=1 --job-name=test --nodelist=node6 -l echo 'test'`

Does not work: 
`sbatch test.slurm` 
with `test.slurm`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --nodelist=node6
#SBATCH --partition=debug

echo 'test'
```

It gives me:

```
PARTITION  AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
debug         up    1:00:00      1  drain node6
```

and I have to resume the node.

All nodes run Debian 9.8, use Infiniband and NIS.
I have made sure that all nodes have the same config, version of packages and daemons running. So, I don't see what I am missing.

Comment: You can see the reason the node went to drain with `scontrol show node node6 | grep Reason`. Or on the slurm controler log files.

Comment: Thanks, Keldorn. That provided some useful information. We finally fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue was connected to the present NIS. Just needed to add to the end of /etc/passwd this line:

```
+::::::
```

and restart slurmd on the node:

```
/etc/init.d/slurmd restart
```